# I can't redraw my CEikRichTextEditor control in Symbian

Tags: symbian

I'm using code below to drag CEikRichTextEditor contents up and down (Scroll) on touch screen devices but the problem is that when I drag the scroll-bar itself (up or down), and then start dragging again (inside the control), the scroll-bar still in its place with no update:

```
void CAIBookDescribtion::HandlePointerEventL(const TPointerEvent& aPointerEvent)
{
static TInt firstpoint;

if(aPointerEvent.iType == TPointerEvent::EButton1Down)
    {
        firstpoint = aPointerEvent.iPosition.iY;
    }



if(aPointerEvent.iType == TPointerEvent::EDrag)
    {
        if(aPointerEvent.iPosition.iY > firstpoint)
            {
                iRichText1->TextView()->ScrollDisplayL(TCursorPosition::EFLineUp);
                iRichText1->UpdateScrollBarsL();
                DrawNow();
                iRichText1->DrawNow();

            }
        else
            {
                iRichText1->TextView()->ScrollDisplayL(TCursorPosition::EFLineDown);
                iRichText1->UpdateScrollBarsL();
                DrawNow();
                iRichText1->DrawNow();
            }
    }

}
```

So how can I refresh (Redraw) the control and its scroll-bar to reflect its contents?

I'm using Symbian C++, S60 5th Ed SDK, Carbide.C++ 2.7, Testing on Nokia E7 (Symbian Anna)

I created the CEikRichTextEditor control using Carbide.C++ 2.7 UI controls.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the scrollbar frame:

iRichText1->ScrollBarFrame()->DrawScrollBarsNow()

[CEikScrollBarFrame, Nokia SDK](http://library.developer.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/S60_5th_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-759FBC7F-5384-4487-8457-A8D4B76F6AA6/html/classCEikScrollBarFrame.html)